# Java duplicated loop output

Tags: java, arrays, string, loops, for-loop

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws FileNotFoundException {
  Scanner LyricsFile = new Scanner(new FileReader("C:/Users/xxxx/Desktop/lyrics.txt"));
  ArrayList<String> LyricsList = new ArrayList<String>();
  while (LyricsFile.hasNext()) {
    String lyricssArray[] = LyricsFile.nextLine().split(" ");

    for (String str : lyricssArray) {
      LyricsList.add(str.replaceAll(",|\\.", ""));
    }
    String[] pangalanStrArray = {"Gagamba", "Araw", "Sanga", "Ulan"};
    String[] panghalipStrArray = {"sila"};
    String[] pangatnigArray = {"At"};
    String[] pandiwaArray = {"Umakyat", "Itinaboy", "Dumating"};
    String[] pangUriStr = {"palaging", "natuyo", "maliliit", "masaya"};
    String[] pangAbayArray = {};
    String[] pangUkolArray = {};
    String[] pangAwiArray = {};
    String[] pangAngkopArray = {"Na"};
    String[] pantukoyArray = {"Ang"};

    ArrayList<String> pangngalan = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (String name : LyricsList) {
      for (String compare : pangalanStrArray) {
        if (name.equalsIgnoreCase(compare) && !pangngalan.contains(compare.toLowerCase())) {
          pangngalan.add(name.toLowerCase());
          break;
        }
      }
    }
    System.out.println("1.Pangngalan: " + pangngalan);
    // break;
  }
}
```

Output looks like this:

```
1.Pangngalan: [gagamba, sanga]
1.Pangngalan: [gagamba, sanga, ulan]
1.Pangngalan: [gagamba, sanga, ulan, araw]
1.Pangngalan: [gagamba, sanga, ulan, araw]
```

BUT I ONLY NEED THIS:

```
1.Pangngalan: [gagamba, sanga, ulan, araw]
```

Please help :( It's kinda strange and I don't know how to remove the duplicates :( It was working fine but then i tried to run it again and it became like that. I didn't even add or removed anything :(

**EDIT**
I tried doing what you guys suggested but it produced an error to the print line and the error says 'PANGNGALAN cannot be resolved to a variable'

Comment: Where is your print statement?

Comment: System.out.println("1.Pangngalan: "+  pangngalan); is this what youre talking about

Comment: Yeah, is that inside the loop or outside?

Comment: I believe it's outside since it's already outside of the three "}"

Comment: Is it inside the `while` loop?

Comment: your bad indentation has fooled you

Comment: and if i add the break; it will only print the first line which is

Comment: Try move the print outside one more '}'

Comment: I did try to move it outside another '}' and it produced an error on 'pangngalan'

Comment: Do you know what scope is in terms of programming?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have your print statement inside the while loop. So it will print in every iteration. So move this line:

```
System.out.println("1.Pangngalan: "+  pangngalan);
```

outside the brackets of your while loop. You will also have to define your list before the while loop. Then your code will look like this:

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws FileNotFoundException {
    Scanner LyricsFile = new Scanner(new FileReader("C:/Users/xxxx/Desktop/lyrics.txt"));
    ArrayList<String> LyricsList = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> pangngalan = new ArrayList<String>();
    while (LyricsFile.hasNext()) {
        String lyricssArray[] = LyricsFile.nextLine().split(" ");

        for (String str : lyricssArray) {
            LyricsList.add(str.replaceAll(",|\\.", ""));
        }
        String[] pangalanStrArray = {"Gagamba", "Araw", "Sanga", "Ulan"};
        String[] panghalipStrArray = {"sila"};
        String[] pangatnigArray = {"At"};
        String[] pandiwaArray = {"Umakyat", "Itinaboy", "Dumating"};
        String[] pangUriStr = {"palaging", "natuyo", "maliliit", "masaya"};
        String[] pangAbayArray = {};
        String[] pangUkolArray = {};
        String[] pangAwiArray = {};
        String[] pangAngkopArray = {"Na"};
        String[] pantukoyArray = {"Ang"};

        for (String name : LyricsList) {
            for (String compare : pangalanStrArray) {
                if (name.equalsIgnoreCase(compare) && !pangngalan.contains(compare.toLowerCase())) {
                    pangngalan.add(name.toLowerCase());
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("1.Pangngalan: " + pangngalan);
}
```

Comment: pangngalan cannot be resolved to a variable :(

Comment: You forgot to move the `pangngalan` array out of the while loop so that the print statement could reference it.

Comment: Yep. You are right. I have edited my answer

Comment: IT WORKED. THANK YOU GUYS SO MUCH THANK YOU

Comment: Downvoters please review this answer.

Comment: It's nothing against you personally but I'm going to leave my downvote there for now because only half of the issue was explained. OP got the answer s/he was looking for, but I'm sure s/he doesn't know why that works, and you didn't try to explain why that fixes the problem.

Comment: @Scrambo now you find this answer isn't useful but the OP have accepted it as correct. I think that your comment reveals that you haven't understood what downvotes are for.

Comment: @JuanCarlosMendoza I was looking through some guidelines for upvoting to see if you were right, and it turns out you [were.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions). I will remove my down-vote as you answered the question in good faith. (although the *why* is missing)

Please remember however, it's not helpful to beginners to get the code without understanding why the solution works.